# How should I concatenate arrays

Tags: java

I am using a function that returns some integers

```
int[] return;
```

This function is inside a loop like this

```
public static int[] toEOBArray(double[] tempVal) 
{
    int[] out;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        out = fixArray(tempVal[i]);
    }
    return out;
}
```

What I want is as new arrays come from `fixArray` to add them to the previous results, so in the end I have a big array that will contain all the small arrays resulting from `fixArray`

What is the most efficient way of doing this?
My main problem is not knowing how to initialize the array that is to hold all the values.

Comment: **Use an Array List then** !!

Comment: What's the purpose of the `in` argument if you don't ever use it?

Comment: @ChetanKinger fixed it. Also yes I am reading the javadoc for ArrayList and its probably what I want. But Ill have to change my other functions too in order to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to work only with arrays, you must first find the length of the concatenated array. Then you can use `System.arraycopy` to copy the small arrays to the output array.

```
public static int[] toEOBArray(double[] in) 
{
    int[][] arrays = new int[10][];
    int len = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        arrays[i] = fixArray(tempVal[i]);
        len += arrays[i].length;
    }
    int[] out = new int[len];
    int offset = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        System.arraycopy(arrays[i],0,out,offset,arrays[i].length);
        offset += arrays[i].length;
    }
    return out;
}
```

Comment: And that effort only because some programmer still like to use arrays... But ok, it's their choice.

Comment: @Tom I agree that using only arrays involves more code, and I would probably prefer to use a Collection to aggregate the arrays, but using arrays also has performance benefits (at least finding the required length of the output array in advance does - if you know the final length, you can initialize an ArrayList with that capacity and have similar performance).

Comment: @Eran I am working on this using Eclipse and I get a `The variable arrays can only be null at this location` warning. Does that have any significance?

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on working with native arrays (as opposed to a Collection like ArrayList) then you will want to use [ArrayUtils class](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.4/index.html) from [Apache Common Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/)  that adds many Collection-like features to Java native arrays, one of which is addAll:

```
ArrayUtils.addAll(fixArray, tempVal);
```